# How to fix ' UT010050: Filter richfaces used in filter mapping SERVLET - Faces Servlet not found'

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I have a EJB and WEB project which has `main.jsp` and several other java classes built in JBOSS 5 with old richfaces 3.3.3. I now want to migrate the project to Wildlfy 13 server with open JDK 11 compilation. But getting the below error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host. 
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./SiamLogWeb: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010050: Filter richfaces used in filter mapping SERVLET - Faces Servlet not found
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed 
failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010050: Filter richfaces used in filter mapping SERVLET - Faces Servlet not found
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010050: Filter richfaces used in filter mapping SERVLET - Faces Servlet not found"},
    "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available`
```

I have removed the old richfaces 3.3.3 jars and placed new richfaces 4.5 JARs which are compatible with Wildfly 13. Also the code is error free and can generate the EAR. But while deploying into wildfly 13 server getting the error

My web.xml looks like:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Project</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.JSF_CONFIG_NAME</param-name>
    <param-value>myfaces-2.2.12</param-value>
</context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
    <param-value>enable</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
  </context-param>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>
```

Comment: wild guess:  tried changing the order and have the servlet first?

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje tried but getting the same as above:
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010050: Filter richfaces used in filter mapping SERVLET - Faces Servlet not found

Answer (score 0):

You are registering a filter but you don't provide any definition (i.e. a `<filter>` element). On the other hand I'm fairly sure you don't need that filter in RF 4 so just delete it.

Comment: Hi @makhiel ERROR WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: class javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator=org.richfaces.javascript.LibraryFunctionImplementation@17433225 and class javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator=org.richfaces.javascript.LibraryFunctionImplementation@25b5fd9a "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available."

Comment: @animeshsahani looks like you are including something twice, what are the jars that you're using?

Comment: Hi @makhiel
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
cssparser-0.9.18.jar
guava-19.0.jar
jhighlight-1.0.jar
jsf-api-2.0.jar
richfaces-a4j-4.5.17.Final-sources.jar
richfaces-a4j-4.5.17.Final.jar
richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final-sources.jar
richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar
richfaces-page-fragments-4.5.17.Final.jar
richfaces-rich-4.5.17.Final-sources.jar
richfaces-rich-4.5.17.Final.jar
sac-1.3.jar

Comment: `*-sources.jar` are uncompiled files, you don't need them in the project. (Btw. where did you get "richfaces-rich" from? that's not the right filename.)

Comment: Hi @makhiel:
i have removed all the sources.jar and got the below error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: class javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter ERROR MSC000001: Failed to start serviceWFLYCTL0013"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services"java.lang.Runtime java.lang.RuntimeException: 
"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start
WFLYCTL0448: 1 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed

Comment: Hi @makhiel
I got all the richfaces jars from the zip file downloaded from richfaces website https://downloads.jboss.org/richfaces/releases/4.5.X/4.5.17.Final/richfaces-distribution-4.5.17.Final.zip
(richfaces-distribution-4.5.17.Final.zip) which includes richfaces-a4j-4.5.17.Final.jar, richfaces-a4j-4.5.17.Final-sources.jar, richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar, 
richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final-sources.jar, richfaces-rich-4.5.17.Final.jar, richfaces-rich-4.5.17.Final-sources.jar